# Цветовая палитра на C#

Tags: c#, winforms, color, dialog

[image: Рисунок 1]
[image: Рисунок 2]

Всем день добрый! Пытаюсь создать цветовой редактор, на примере рисунка 1, пока получается что-то как на рисунке 2.

Суть в том, что пользователь выбирает цвет через colordialog, этот цвет применяется к центральному квадрату, а остальные должны отображать оттенки этого цвета.

На данном этапе работает только заполнение цветом первого квадрата через colordialog, дальше не знаю как работать с цветом, надеюсь на обратную связь.

P.S. Возможно неточно объяснил, если остались вопросы пишите ;)

Comment: Какой тип приложения? Winforms, WPF, Unity? Покажите ваш код. `дальше не знаю как работать с цветом` что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: @aepot, я думаю, что ему не понятно, как рассчитывать оттенки цвета.

Comment: @SurfaceStack судя по скриншоту, там просто яркость. Чтобы поменять яркость, надо добавить или отнять от всех компонент цвета одно и то же число. Ну а в целом надо научиться переводить RGB в HSB и обратно.

Comment: @aepot, я уже думал над этим, но это подходит не для каждого цвета. [Вот](https://colorscheme.ru/#) c которого копируется редактор.

Comment: @aepot Моя проблема в том, что colordialog выдает цвет в  шестнадцатеричном формате, а чтобы отнять от всех компонент цвета одно и то же число нужно знать цвет в формате RGB абсолютный.

Comment: @aepot тип приложения Winforms

Comment: [Создайте из этого кода цвет](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2109771/12888024).

Comment: @aepot Не подскажете как?

Comment: Нажмите на текст "Создайте из этого кода цвет"